# Passing an array from IronPython to C# library

Tags: c#, ironpython

I am trying to understand how to pass a multi-dimensional array of float from IronPython code to a C# library.

Here is the C# code I am trying to call (This is a function is a library class I am importing into my IronPython code):

```
public void ShowMessage(double[,] values)
```

This is the my IronPython code:

```
import clr
clr.AddReferenceToFile(r"DisplayLib.dll")
from DisplayLib import Display

display = Display()

a = [[1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5],
     [2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5]]

display.ShowMessage(a)
```

I am getting the following exception: "expected Array[float], got list" then I tried to convert the array to a tuple but it only worked for a 1D array.

Any suggestions on how do this?

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to create an instance of a Two-Dimensional .NET array.  You cannot use Python lists in place of arrays.  An unfortunate limitation.

You could try something like this:

```
from System import Array

data = [[1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5],
        [2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5]]
# assuming all rows will have the same length
a = Array.CreateInstance(float, len(data), len(data[0]))
for i, row in enumerate(data):
    for j, col in enumerate(row):
        a[i, j] = col
display.ShowMessage(a);
```